# Why was my answer deleted

Tags: support

I don't know if y'all can see the deleted item:

[Keyboard command/shortcut to resize window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44698/keyboard-command-to-make-window-smaller)

But I can.

No comment left to indicate why.  So I'm wondering what line I crossed...

Comment: I can see how this was mistaken for a comment, I too had to re-read it a couple of time before I understood it's really an answer. Maybe you could edit it to be more clear?

Answer (score 2):

It was flagged as not being an answer, and it appeared you were simply placing a comment saying "Thanks I see what to do now" in the Answer box. Re-reading it several times now and I'm still confused with the content of the answer itself, though it's now undeleted.

Comment: OK thanks.  Yeah I considered deleting the question when I worked out a way to fix my problem about a minute later.  Then I decided to leave it because I couldn't find the answer elsewhere...